# How do I install the HP F4280 printer?

Tags: installation, printing, hp

How do I install the HP Deskjet F4280 All-in-One printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an HP F4280 too and it works out of the box with 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10.  Just "start it up and plug it in"... prints beautiful and scans great with XSane and SimpleScan.

Answer (score 2):

**HOWTO**: Install HP Printers for Beginners
This is a little guide on how to correctly install an HP printer, since so many people seem to have trouble with this. I have also provided a very basic scanner start up guide. Here are the steps:

**Printing:**

First of all, connect your printer to your computer, and turn it on.

See if your printer gets autodetected by Ubuntu. If it does, something will pop up saying it is configured for use and is ready.

If nothing happens, simply go to System > Administration > Printing > New.

If it doesn't find any or doesn't recognize your printer, try the following:

First check on [this website](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html) if your printer is compatible with linux.

If it is compatible, then follow the instructions on [this page](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) to install and configure the drivers.

**Scanning:**

For HP all-in-ones (such as the PSC series), after you have followed the above steps, put the paper you want to scan in the scanner and then go to Applications > Graphics > XSane Image scanning program. In XSane, click "scan" and then when it's done, click save as and save it wherever you want.

If you have a sole HP scanner, then you could try to just plug it in, turn it on, and try to scan it with XSane, but I don't gurantee that it will work.

***NOTE: If you want to send a scan that you made on your linux box to a windows computer, it won't open it up. You have to right-click on the image, and go to "open with GIMP Image Editor". Then go to save as and click on "select file type (by extension)". Then scroll down to JPEG format and click ok as many times so that it saves. It'll then be readable in windows.

Comment: No need to manually download hplip, it's in the archive and is actively backported to -backports.